# TDBGrid Disable autosort after insert

Tags: delphi

This is my problem : I want to disable `tdbgrid` auto-sort after inserting a new record. I want `tdbgrid` perform sort ONLY IF the user ask them (clicking the column title).

I have a table named `f4400` and has two columns, `sec_code` and `sec_desc`(both are varchar).
Let say that may table contains these records:

```
sec_code          sec_desc
1 , section 1     xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
2 , section 2     xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
3 , section 3     xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

when I query `f4400` and put it in the `tdbgrid`, both looked the same. When I insert a new record, let say ("11", "section 11"), my grid would now look like these :

```
sec_code          sec_desc
1 , section 1     xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx 
2 , section 2     xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx 
3 , section 3     xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx 
11 , section 11   xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

so far so good. now, I will sort my grid by `sec_code` desc. My `tdbgrid` will now look like this:

```
3 , section 3     xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
2 , section 2     xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
1 , section 1     xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
11 , section 11   xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

now, I will insert a new record let say ("21", "section 21"), tdbgrid will gave me a result of :

```
sec_code          sec_desc
3 , section 3     xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
2 , section 2     xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
21 , section 21   xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
1 , section 1     xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
11 , section 11   xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

The result I wanted is :

```
sec_code          sec_desc
3 , section 3     xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
2 , section 2     xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
1 , section 1     xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
11 , section 11   xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
21 , section 21   xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

The row position of "sec_code 21" is my problem. I inserted it at the bottom of the `tdbgrid` so i want to see "sec_code 21" at the bottom of the grid.

I tried using `tdbgrid.datasource.dataset.sort := ''` but it will give a an output like this:

```
sec_code          sec_desc
1 , section 1     xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
11 , section 11   xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
2 , section 2     xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
21 , section 21   xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
3 , section 3     xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

I tried using tdbgrid.datasource.dataset.IndexFielName := '' but it will give a an output like this:

```
sec_code          sec_desc
1 , section 1     xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
2 , section 2     xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
3 , section 3     xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
11 , section 11   xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
21 , section 21   xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

The position of "sec_code 21" is not my problem anymore, but, the positions of "sec_code 1,2,3 and 11" are not in there positions i wanted. i sorted sec_code 1,2,3 and 11 descending so i want to see sec_code 1,2,3 and 11(not including sec_code 21) to be sorted descending.

hope you understand my problem and would try to suggest how can i give solution to that. It's been headache to me for about 3-4 nights.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please take the time to provide proper sample data and format it in a way that's actually readable. As a hint, you can preview your post realtime in the area immediately below where you're typing it. Not only does properly formatting it save others from having to do so, it also means that your question is more readable and understandable, and therefore much more likely to get you an answer more quickly. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 2):

The sort order in `TDBGrid` is determined by the index order in the underlying dataset.

Your `sec_code` column is apparently a string/char, and is therefore being sorted as one by the index you have on that column; that explains why the sort order you want isn't the one you're getting.

If you append a row at the end of the dataset, and want it to stay there, you need to set the `IndexName` to `''` (meaning there's no index order).

If you want them to sort in actual numeric order (1, 2, 3, 11, 21), you need to convert them to numeric.

The final output you're looking for makes no sense, though. You're looking for a descending sort of the values `1, 2, 3, 11, 21` and expecting it to come out `3, 2, 1, 11, 21`. There's no logic there. A valid expectation on numeric types 2ould be `21, 11, 3, 2, 1`; a valid expectation for character types would be `3, 21, 2, 11, 1`. There's no combination that would give you the results you're looking for except for an actual insertion order, where there is no index in effect and you specifically added the rows in the `3, 2, 1, 11, 21` sequence.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've seen the limitations DBGrid so I switch to Virtual string tree. For guys out there that wanted your grid to be more presentable and haven't use Virtual String Tree + Free, try using it. Again, thanks..